# How to create a navigation menu in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, menu, navigation

At work I am using a software which name cannot be mentioned and which content information I need to hide. However, as you can see below, there is a navigation menu on the left-hand side of the application. What is it and how can I create a menu like this in C# using WPF?

[image: Navigation]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to create Such Menu you can use `WPF Ribbon`.

**WPF Ribbon(from MSDN):**

The `ribbon` control is made up several components. Every ribbon has an *Application Menu, a Quick Access Toolbar, tabs, groups, and controls*. `Ribbon` tabs contain groups, and each group contains controls. `Ribbon` controls include simple controls such as **buttons, check boxes, and text boxes; and menu controls such as combo boxes, split buttons, and menu buttons**. Related controls can be further combined into control groups. In addition to the required components, a ribbon can also include optional components, such as contextual tabs, enhanced ToolTips, and galleries.

**[Ream more on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff799534%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**

**[WPF Ribbon Example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0b73e1/ribbon-control-in-wpf-4-5/)**

Hope this helped you!

Comment: Im sorry for this late comment but how does the  Ribbon correspond with the screenshot the TS posted?